# How to chain rules using TokensRegex?

Tags: stanford-nlp

First of all, kudos to Angel Chang for writing such a great tool as TokensRegex!
My use case is the following: 
I have two extraction rules in my test rule set. Both of them have the "action" field specified as the outcome and both have "Annotate" in the action list. 
They work just fine when the second rule's expression to match is independent of the first rule's outcome. But when the second rule execution depends on the outcome of the first rule, things break down. 
A specific example:
I have the following sentence: "*The consensus estimates called for EPS of $3.55 on revenues of $30.51 billion.*"
"EPS" and "revenues" are already annotated by a more basic RegexNER annotator. The goal of TokensRegex annotator is to augment the NER annotations if certain conditions are met.
In this simplified example if we see a term "estimate(s)" occuring shortly before the term "EPS", we want to re-tag the token "EPS" with the "DN-EPS_EST" NER annotation. That's my first rule.
The second rule is dependent on the result of the first rule - re-annotate the token "revenues" if it is preceeded by a token with the NER annotation of "DN-EPS_EST" (which can **only** be the outcome of the first rule).
So my TokensRegex rules are the following:

```
{
ruleType:   "tokens",
pattern:    ( /[Ee]stimates?/ []{0,3} [{ner:"DN-EPS"}] ),
action:     ( Annotate($0[-1], "ner", "DN-EPS_EST") ) }
{
ruleType:   "tokens",
pattern:    ( [{ner:"DN-EPS_EST"}] /of/ [{ner:"MONEY"}]{1,3} /on/ [{ner:"DN-REVENUE"}] ),
action:     ( Annotate($0[-1], "ner", "DN-REVENUE_EST") ) }
```

The first rule works, but the second doesn't. What could the problem be? Are the rules executed in a wrong order? Are the results of the first rule not persisted on time for being matched in the second expression? Am I using wrong fields or action type? I intentionally simplified the pattern matching expressions in this example, but maybe I still have an error in the "pattern" field of the second rule?
Any help at all will be greatly appreciated! I am stumped. Read all the documentation on the website, the Javadocs and the slides even, but just can't find a specific answer.

Comment: Just to clarify: I am using TokensRegexAnnottator provided, I am not writing my own annotator to add/modify annotations, so I assume that the "result" field is not useful for me and that the "action" field is the only way to change annotations using this framework. If it's not the case, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

OK, after some additional tinkering and research I finally found the answer to my own question:
**You have to apply the chained rules in stages**, just ordering them "correctly" in the rules file is not sufficient.
TokensRegexAnnotator will DO NOTHING based on the dependent rule if its pattern mentions a token property that is being modified by the upstream rule and if the stage is the same (or unspecified). It will match neither the "before the 1st rule execution" state, nor the "after the 1st rule execution" state.
 
I tested the 2nd rule by itself by taking the 1st rule out of the equation altogether - it worked. This was necessary to ensure that the pattern expression was not faulty in the 2nd rule.
 
Then I re-introduced the 1st rule and tested the 2nd rule with two expressions: "before the 1st rule execition" state and "after the 1st rule execution" state - NOTHING HAPPENED IN BOTH CASES. Not sure why TokensRegexAnnotator was implemented this way, maybe the creators thought that no behavior is better than some default behavior...
At any rate, only after I read deeper into the "SequenceMatchRules" Javadoc, I found the "stage" field and attempted to apply it (although it does not say explicitly that you HAVE to apply it if you have a rule that uses output annotations from some other rule).
Here's how the working example looks like:

```
{   ruleType:   "tokens",
pattern:    ( /[Ee]stimates?/ []{0,3} [{ner:"DN-EPS"}] ),
action:     ( Annotate($0[-1], "ner", "DN-EPS_EST") ),
stage:      1   }

{   ruleType:   "tokens",
pattern:    ( [{ner:"DN-EPS_EST"}] /of/ [{ner:"MONEY"}]{1,3} /on/ [{ner:"DN-REVENUE"}] ),
action:     ( Annotate($0[-1], "ner", "DN-REVENUE_EST") ),
stage:      2   }
```

As you can see, the 2nd rule's pattern has a condition on an NER annotation that can be satisfied only after the 1st rule is executed and results are committed. In this example the 2nd rule is fired, as expected.

Comment: Happy to hear that you are using TokensRegex and that you figured out how to chain the rules using stages.  The basic idea is that for rules that occur in the same stage, TokensRegex will figure out the "best" matched (based on priority and length of match), and only trigger action for that rule.  It may make sense to have an always tigger action mode.  I'm happy to hear suggestions for improving TokensRegex.

Comment: @AngelChang Where can I find detailed documentation for framing the rules using TokensRegex, https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokensregex.html#Questions does not document this Annotate() function above